# Can we determine the distance from a radio station (antenna) and a receiver using radio wave ?

Tags: waves, distance, radio

say we have the a receiver and radio antenna can we calculate the distance between the receiver and the antenna by a receiver if we know the frequency ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@probably_someone suggested one method that requires timing synchronization between the transmitter and the receiver and that is indeed the simplest when available. Note that you can also measure distance by triangulation with two receivers at known distances apart such that these are synchronized with each other but without being synchronized to the transmitter. Two receivers are the minimum but more accurate results can be had if at least 3 receivers are used.

This idea also works for acoustic propagation and is widely used, for example, to estimate the location of a weapon firing a bullet.

Comment: This is probably the more applicable method in most real cases. It's also basically how GPS determines your location, by communicating with satellites (although the process you're talking about is apparently called trilateration in the industry, rather than triangulation: https://gisgeography.com/trilateration-triangulation-gps/)

Answer (score 2):

For long distances, you can use the timing of the signal to judge distance. Have the antenna broadcast a beep (or some other easily-identifiable signal) exactly at noon (or some other agreed-upon time). Your receiver will receive the signal slightly later; the time delay $t$ is related to the distance $d$ by the following relation:

$$d=ct$$

where $c$ is the speed of light.

Note that since the speed of light is extremely high (it travels about a foot (30 cm) per nanosecond, as a rule of thumb), this approach will require extremely precise timing for short distances.